# Comparision between dates

Tags: android, database, date

In my application i have to retrieve date from database which lies between some dates.In my database i am storing date as string.I also wrote the query.

This is my sample table:

```
id    item  price  startdate    enddate
1     ass    78    04/08/2012   14/09/2012
2     err    89    04/08/2012   10/09/2012.
3     dffg   44    04/08/2012   18/08/2012
```

My query is :

```
public Cursor getIncometitle(String grpsdb,String date) throws SQLException
{   
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(
             "SELECT * FROM incomexpense WHERE date like '"+date+"' OR enddate > date  AND category='Income' AND groups='"+grpsdb +"'   ORDER BY date DESC" , null);
if (mCursor != null) {
mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
return mCursor;
}
```

In the above condition i am checking `enddate>date`. In this what is coming is,i think its comparing the dates `(04 and 14) and(04and 10)`,it is greater so all the data is coming .But i don't need that,if `enddate month is greater that startdate` means i have to get the data.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you explain this a little further, I can't understand which is the question? Do you want SQL to only compare the months?

Comment: luanjoit ..I will explain my scenario clearly.in my above table start date and end date is there..Some of the end dates lies in next month and some in this month.Now if i am going to display data for next month means i have to show the item which end date lies in next month.So i checked the condition if end date is gretaer than current date i have to retrieve that data..as i said in my question it is comparng the date and gives all item.Because the enddate(14,18,10) all is coming,.But my query should return (data which month lies in next month)(i.e)item 1 nd 2 should come.

Comment: you can check this for sqlite http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg08.htm

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the SQL injection attack vulnerability (use parameterized queries instead of inserting values directly into your SQL) you should store your dates in a sortable format, e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd`. At that point, a lexicographic ordering will also give you the right chronological ordering, so your comparisons will work.

If you *can*, it would actually be better if you could store your dates *as dates* in the database - it depends on whether your database supports that.